# Determine the fourier seriers for the periodic function

Tags: fourier-series

I need help to determine the Fourier series for the periodic function of:

$$f(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}-2 &:&-\pi< x<-\pi/2\\
2 &:&-π/2<x<π/2\\
      \\-2 &:& π/2<x<π
\end{array}\right..$$

Find the values of $a$'s and $b$'s and solve the equation.

[Here is an image of the function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ez4O.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I am new on the topic and do not understand it.

Comment: Look up Fourier Series and show your attempts beneath your question for optimal reception from other forum users/so you do not get this question put 'On Hold' by moderators

Comment: Check this out: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-signals/ee-fourier-series/v/ee-fourier-series-intro